# Making the "else if" part of the outer statement according to language semantics?

Tags: c, parsing, if-statement, conditional-statements, semantics

Say we have the following C statement:

```
if( cond) 
      if( cond) 
        stat
      else
        stat
```

where the 'else stat' is part of the inner if statement according to the language semantics. What would I need to do in order to make the 'else stat' be part of the outer if statement? To my knowledge, adding `{}` after the then and at the end of the if statement to separate them would work. Is this correct? Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: There is no `then` in [tag:c]!

Comment: Use braces around the nested `if` so it is unambiguous.  GCC will recommend doing that if used with the correct options.  It is the only way to do it.  Why would you want an alternative anyway?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i just wanted to see if there is another way of doing this.  My textbook explains that there is other ways, but doesnt say what they are. Tried researching them, but no luck. so ya. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Where is the `then` coming from?  That's not C.

Comment: Why would one down-vote all the answers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case you should use the compound statement

```
if( cond1 )
{
      if ( cond2 ) 
        stat;
}
else
{
    stat;
}
```

Another approach from the point of view of the C syntax but less readable and should not be used is the following

```
if( cond1 )
      if ( cond2 ) 
        stat;
      else
        ; // empty statement
else
      stat;
```

However such an approach can be used then the internal if contains another else if. For example

```
if( cond1 )
      if ( cond2 ) 
        stat;
      else if ( cond3 )
        stat;
      else
        ; // empty statement
else
      stat;
```

Or it can be made more readable the following way

```
if( cond1 )
      if ( cond2 ) 
      {
        stat;
      }
      else
      {
        ; // empty statement
      }
else
      stat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to use always use brackets. It makes it much easier for yourself (or others) to read/understand/modify later.

Like this:

```
if (condition1) {
     if (nestedCondition1) {
        //do something
     }
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Then it becomes easy to quickly see which statement you are inside.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to use brackets:

```
if (cond){
    if (cond)
        //inner conditional 
} else {
  //outer conditional 
}
```